# Unity AddForce to Player onTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Screenshot Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GK70.png)"I'm making a game, i want to create a bounce script when the player jumps on a box and bounces
up, this is what i have so far"

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float bounceForce = 3f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll) {
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        Debug.Log("Jumpforce");
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (0,bounceForce,0);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: whats the problem so far?

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a force to the trigger and not the player? I believe you want `coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>` instead of just `GetComponent<Rigidbody>`

Comment: i want the player when he enters the collider'trigger' to bounce up

Comment: i added a Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

i got it

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        Debug.Log("JumpForce Added");
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up*bounceForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```